# How do I install a washing machine when the drain is 7.5 feet high?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

My washing machine drain is 7.5 feet from the floor.  I plan on researching my washer and making sure it can pump that high.  I want to hook it up to a 1.5 inch PVC pipe drain.  The 1.5 pipe is above my main sewer drain.

This leaves me with less than a half foot to connect it to the 1.5 drain pipe.  How should I do that?

Comment: How far above the floor is your main drain?

Comment: I feel like some sort of critical information for understanding this question is missing, like why you have less than 6 inches to connect.

Comment: Also, 1.5 inches is considered too small for a washing machine drain.  2" is standard.

Comment: A picture might help us understand the problem.  If you don't have the rep to include the image, just post a link to your image and someone will edit it in for you

Comment: Most modern washing machines come with a drain line, that happens to be the exact length of the maximum pumping distance of the machine. If your machine has a drain line that was attached to the machine from the factory (or came in the same packaging as the machine), that represents the exact distance the machine can pump waste water (minus ~6" for the hook loop).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear earlier on my current setup.  The washer is currently draining into a large plastic sink that has a pump with a float.  The pump pumps through copper pipe into a 1.5" pvc at the 7.5 foot height. The main drain line is 3" PVC.  The main line has a reducing tee that connects the 1.5" fitting at the 7.5 foot height.

Comment: I want to get rid of the sink because the stagnant water smells, and I hate having to replace the lint trap on the hose frequently and cleaning the pump is also a drag.  So, I plan on removing the sink, and copper pipe, leaving me with a 3" to 1.5" reducing tee PVC.  I am going to have to raise the washer off the ground to get it to pump that high, but what I don't know how to do is connect the hose up to my drain line.

Comment: Typically, the end of the washer drain hose simply sits in a vertical section of drain pipe. The hose isn't sealed to the drain pipe in this approach, so you need (1) enough of a vertical run to ensure the drained water goes down into the pipe and (2) a trap, to prevent sewer gases from entering the home. Your best bet may be to move or extend some drain and ventilation pipe. Post a photo of the setup if you want more detailed advice.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing how the sink you want to remove could be so much higher than the washing machine in the first place. If the machine can drain into the sink now, it should be able to drain into a pipe replacing the sink.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend not doing what you suggest, here's why:

A typical rough-in for a clothes washing machine is as show in the picture below and consists of the following:

- vent
- 2" p-trap
- vertical section of 2" pipe above the p-trap
- (an actual outlet box as shown is not required, you can just use the plan end of the pipe)

Your discharge hose will fit inside the 2" pipe opening and will usually enter the pipe about 6" to 8". This connection is not water/air tight.

The size of the p-trap and the vertical section of pipe are to accommodate for the flow rate of the washing machine's discharge. The p-trap will create a restriction to the flow and the vertical pipe allows for some head water to buildup without putting any back pressure on the washing machine's internal pump.

[image: laundry machine rough-in]

A p-trap is a must as it will prevent sewer gas from entering your house. The vent is required to protect the water seal of the p-trap but can be replaced with an air admittance valve depending on local codes.

I would imagine that if your machine can pump that high it will be near its limit and without any room for a vertical section of pipe to discharge into you will have to make the connection sold which will put additional back pressure on to the machine's pump (even more due to the pipe size only being 1.5") which will shorten the life span of the pump.